# Update the location in the client when change in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I am making an anroid app and using express for backend. 
This my **Delivery Boy Schema**:

```
var DeliveryBoySchema = new Schema({

    name: String,
    college: {type:String},
    password: {type: String, required: true, select: false},
    lat:{type: String},
    long:{type:String}

});
```

When the delivery boy changes it's position, it gets updated in the mongodb.
So, the users i.e the client who are viewing this delivery boy are tracking his position. I have found 2 ways to do that:

**1**.The client calls the api after every 5 sec and gets the current location of the delivery boy.

**2**.I found another interesting way to do that, i.e using sockets.

I am not very clear with it's functioning. I am having a problem in how to update a client when there is a change in the database and the user sees the current location.

Answer (score 4):

Some coding as requested from OP using only `mongoose`, `nodeJS` and `socket`. Actual implementation does not have to be exactly same, but the following should give a general idea on how to proceed and fill the missing gaps. I will be using ES6 capabilities just,  for sake of convenience.

nodeJS version **4.2.2** , socket.io **1.3.5**, mongoose version **4.1.2**, express **4.13.3**

1. Create a socket - server side

```js
//the following is probably your app.js
import express from 'express'
...
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
...

var socketio = require('socket.io')(server, {
  path: '/socket.io-path, //modify this as per your needs
});
//now register created socket object
require('./components/socket')(socketio);

...
//start the server
```

```js
//the following is components/socket/index.js

function onConnect(socket){
   //register listeners on mongo schema changes
   require('../../models/deliveryBoy.socket').register(socket);
}

module.exports = function(socketio){
  socketio.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.address = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress +
      ':' + socket.request.connection.remotePort; 
    //address, e.g. 127.0.0.1:52243

    socket.connectedAt = new Date();
    socket.log = function(...data) {
      console.log(`SocketIO ${socket.address}`, ...data);
    };
    // Call onDisconnect.
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      socket.log('Disconnected: ');
      //do something when user disconnects
    });

    // Call onConnect.
    onConnect(socket);
    socket.log('New connection: ');
  });
};
```

2. Attach a hook on mongoose schema definition

```js
//this is to be stored at ./models/deliveryBoy.model 

'use strict';

var mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var DeliveryBoySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    college: {type:String},
    password: {type: String, required: true, select: false},
    lat:{type: String},
    long:{type:String}
});

//attach a hook to be triggered every time you modify the document
//has to be inserted before the mongoose model is created !!!
//with !!!ATTENTION!!! update method using $set
//for example DeliveryBoy.update({_id:'blah'}, {$set: {long: 1, lat: 0}});
DeliveryBoySchema.post('update', function(){
 var update = this._update;
 if (update.$set && (update.$set.lat || update.$set.long)){
  try{
   var updatedObjectId = this._conditions._id; //will serve as a room
            var newLoc = {
              lat: update.$set.lat,
              long: update.$set.long
            }
   //now emit the event using nodejs event emitter

            require('../../components/app.events').emit('updateLoc', {roomId: updatedObjectId, newLoc: newLoc}); 
  }
 }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('DeliveryBoy', DeliveryBoySchema);
```

3. Socket listener for DeliveryBoy

```js
//this is the component which implement socket specifically for delivery boy model
//it is called (register method) from general components/socket module

exports.register = function(socket){
  AppEvents.on('updateLoc', function(socket){
    return function(info){
      socket.to(info.roomId).emit('newLocation', info.newLoc);
    }
  });
}
```

4. Now you just need to connect to the room from client side based on the deliveryboy id and consume messages from client side and update your view accordingly

One more thing, this is how you update the database from your REST API

```js
app.put('/update/:gameId', function(req, res){
    DeliveryBoy.update({_id: req.params.gameId}, {$set: req.body}, function(err){
      res.send(200); //of course this needs to be handled properly, but i am too tired after typing all these
      //you owe me couple beers dude
});
});
```

**P.S** The code is kinda messy, but you should be able to make corresponding improvements. If have any question let me know. But basic concepts should be clear

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 is not good, simply because your server will be bloated and unable to respond in no time. Forget about this :) Simply put, the position should be queried from your server only once, first time the app is loaded.

You might consider a delivery boy to be a game. Suppose for simplicity that there is only 1 player and several viewers. Player is the one triggering update in position. Viewers can only track the change. Essentially player and viewers are in the same room, meaning them and only them should be updated whenever change occurs.

- From player point of view, it is quite simple, he is the only one who can affect the position, you can simultaneously ask server to update the position of the delivery boy and change its position on your view. No issue here. Every time your player changes the position of the delivery boy, you are absolutely required to persistently store the update.
- From the viewers point of view. Every time the update in position occurs in your data storage you need to notify every one connected to the room about the change in position. And there are multiple ways to go about this. But most probably you will have to use sockets one way or the other (except for some XMPP client side solutions, which are far more complicated)

Simply put the key is to choose right communication channel. Personally I would go with redis to store the position, creating subscription channels and publishing updates through channels to sockets. Once the position is updated, you persistently update the position in redis, publish the change to the channel (via the queue), consume the change through subscription and pass the update the all listening clients via sockets. 
Why redis? 1. Good for distributed systems (can scale) 2. PUB/SUB is a queue, no need to earn a cancer trying to synchronise 3. PUB/SUB is persistent 4. Actually faster than pure database solutions (comparing to MongoDB)

Comment: Actually,I am almost done with my app. This thing is left. It would be great if you tell me how to use it with mongodb and node,js

Comment: I looking to use it with mongodb and node js and not able to find any solution to it.

Comment: It is possible to build using mongodb as well. It is far more tricky and more difficult to scale. However you are really constraint to use mongodb, you might want to look at mongodb hooks, track the updates on the mongo documents and push them to sockets. I will update the answer itself, if you wish

Comment: can you help me out with this?

Comment: sure, please wait few hours, will reply once I get back home from work :)